# Something got wrong in putting two bullet lists in the same div left/right

Tags: html, css

in [this](http://glamourina.pl/media-o-mnie/) page, on the top, I had the two bullet lists called "Artykuły o mnie w mediach" and "Moje publikacje" in the same space.

"Artykuły o mnie w mediach" was showing on the left.
"Moje publikacje" was showing on the right.

I added a new link to the left URL, I then increased of 20px the sizes of `.mediaomnielistright ul` and `.mediaomnielistleft` and then it got disrupted. Now instead than showing one list next to the other, they are showing one on the top and on on the bottom.

I have tried to revert all the changes I made, but for some reason it's still showing wrong.

This is the css in use right now:

```
#col2{width:580px; height: auto;}
.mediaomnielistright ul{margin-left:5px; list-style-type: circle; padding-left:20px;}
.mediaomnielistleft ul{list-style-type: circle; padding-left:20px;}
.mediaomnielist {overflow:auto; height:580px;}
.mediaomnielistleft {width:310px; float:left; height:inherit;}
.mediaomnielistright {width:288px; border-left-width:2px; border-style:dashed; border-color:#999; overflow: auto; height:inherit;
}
```

Anybody knows what's wrong?

Comment: Your containing `div` is `580px` in width (even smaller with the scrollbar). Your two child `div` elements equal 598px (288+310) in width. They are too wide to fit side by side inside the container. The other child falls below the other one because you're using `float` which is just the way it is supposed to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You increased the width of the left one? Meaning that there was not enough room left in the parent `<div>` for them to be displayed side by side. Instead of using absolute values, use percentages:

```
mediaomnielistleft, mediaomnielistright { width:49%; }
```

It doesn't add up to 100% because you have a scrollbar on the right hand side of the parent div. This takes up about `16px`.

Alternatively you could stick to using actual widths and change

```
mediaomnielistright { width: 251px; }
```

Comment: Thanks, I really like the idea to use a percentage. I will even increase the whole big column, because I can see there is more space left in the right. The links and all the stuff will be more readable. Having % I won't have to play so much with finding the right pixel size for every div.

Comment: @Pikk Exactly! And it tends to make things easier if you want responsive sites.

Answer (score 3):

580px is less than 310px + 288px, so you just have no room for these columns.

Answer (score 0):

```
 .mediaonilist { width :580 px}
 .mediomnielistleft { width : 310 px}
 .mediomnielistleft { width : 290 px}
```

310+290=600
So the float is ignored. And i don't count the margin and the padding.